# Cannot looping DataGridView null values

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to loop through the `DataGridView` rows and then send the values for an update in my SQL-DB. I can make the update, but the program crashes when I come to the end of the rows, because then it read a null-value.

> Exception: System.NullReferenceException, Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I have two questions:

- Why can't I stop the method with return (see below) with my if
  statement?
- How can I let the loop insert null values in the strings? Some of
  my columns it's OK to send null-values to. And some not, is there
  any way to choose which?

  ```
  private void editEmployeeDGV()
  {
      foreach (DataGridViewRow row in employeeDataGridView.Rows)
      {
          if (row.Cells["SocialSNColumn"].Value.ToString() == null)
          {
              return;
          }

          string SocialSN = row.Cells["SocialSNColumn"].Value.ToString();
          string Name = row.Cells["nameColumn"].Value.ToString();
          string Surname = row.Cells["SurnameColumn"].Value.ToString();
          string Email = row.Cells["EmailColumn"].Value.ToString();
          string TelNr = row.Cells["TelNrColumn"].Value.ToString();
          string Gender = row.Cells["GenderColumn"].Value.ToString();
          string ECName = row.Cells["ECNameColumn"].Value.ToString();
          string ECNumber = row.Cells["ECNumberColumn"].Value.ToString();

          cont.editEmployeeDGV(SocialSN, Name, Surname, Email, TelNr, Gender, ECName, ECNumber);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: @GrantWinney, of course. Sorry! Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the exception is that you're trying to call the `ToString()` method on the `Value` property, but it's `null`.

```
if (row.Cells["SocialSNColumn"].Value.ToString() == null)
{
    return;
}
```

There's no reason to cast to a string first; just test for `null`:

```
if (row.Cells["SocialSNColumn"].Value == null)
{
    return;
}
```

Your other lines of code run the same risk of throwing an NRE if any of their `Value` properties are `null`. To avoid those, you may want to replace `ToString()` with the `Convert.ToString()` method, which replaces `null` with an empty string:

```
string SocialSN = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["SocialSNColumn"].Value);
string Name = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["nameColumn"].Value);
```